# Vim: running a command in the editor instead of shelling out

Tags: vim

When I do something like `!git init` inside of vim it switches over to bash and runs the command there then says "Press Enter to continue".

From what I've read and seen I thought it would run the command in the bottom area of vim (in a buffer maybe?).

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a setting I messed up on?

---

While that git plugin does look interesting I'm watching a TekPub demo where he is doing things like !bundle install as well and the result is just displayed at the bottom (under where he typed the command) in vim directly.

Also I am using vim in Ubuntu if that matters.

Comment: Try http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Close voters: Vim + Git is programming-related.

Comment: So currently it seems like this is just a MacVim thing.. is there any plugin or way to do this in normal vim with ANY external command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior I have (and have always had) when using console Vim. The behavior that you were expecting is what I get when using GUI Vim (e.g., MacVim or GVim). So, to answer your question: no, you are not doing anything wrong, and there are no messed up settings.

Comment: Okay -- this makes sense.  I was watching a video and it's entirely possible (likely) even that the guy was using MacVim.

Answer (score 3):

If you're specifically wanting to use Git, checkout Tim Pope's fugitive plugin.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975

Comment: From the example in the question I think that it's exactly what the asker is after.

Comment: While the particular example is regarding Git usage, I believe the actual question is why when running an external command (*like* git), the results are coming up in a full window instead of the command-line window at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Jeet: While I think you're probably right, I figured this is most likely what he's after.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
:read !command
```

to insert output in current buffer. So, for example, if you want to insert the current date:

```
:r !date
```